# Apache Cordova - Application doesn't work on Android 2.2.3

Tags: android, apache, cordova

I have created a new project. On Android 5 it works perfectly. I am trying to run on 2.3.3 but during installation I am getting a message "There is a problem parsing the package".

I think I need set minSdkVersion 8 for Android 2.2.3:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
```

but the compilation fails:

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in ..AndroidManifest.xml
```

If I set 14, the application installation also doesn't work on 2.2.3. 
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: I think you will need to chage the minSdkLevel to 8 in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: The minimum Android version which is supported by cordova is Ice Cream Sandwich, that is SDK 14. You need to install an old version of cordova, if you wish to use old Androids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Cordova release that supports Android 2.2 is the [2.9](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide).

As reported in the latest Cordova documentation (bold is mine):

> Cordova supports Android 4.0.x (starting with Android API level 14) and higher. **As a general rule, Android versions become unsupported by Cordova as they dip below 5% on Google's distribution dashboard**. Android versions earlier than API level 10, and the 3.x versions (Honeycomb, API levels 11-13) fall significantly below that 5% threshold.